# Syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm trying to get this while loop (using nano) to download some websites from this URL but I keep getting the error "syntax error near unexpected token `done'":

```
while read <FIRST-LAST> do
        echo FIRST-LAST
        curl -O https://www.uoguelph.ca/arts/history/people/FIRST-LAST
done < formatted_history.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Either the `do` should appear on a new line, or it needs to have a semi-colon inserted in front of it
- `<FIRST-LAST>` should actually be the name of a shell variable, and `FIRST-LAST` should be a reference to that variable.  `<` and `>` are not legal characters for shell variables, so we can deduce that something else must be substituted here instead.  `person` seems to be as good a variable name as any in this particular case.

I think something like this should work much better:

```
while read person ; do
        echo "${person}"
        curl -O "https://www.uoguelph.ca/arts/history/people/${person}"
done < formatted_history.txt
```

This assumes that the file `formatted_history.txt` actually exists in the current directory and is a list of people from the https://www.uoguelph.ca/arts/history/people/ page - something like:

```
tara-abraham
donna-andrew
susan-armstrong-reid
... etc ...
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This worked perfectly, I can't explain how long this has taken me and you just answered it. Thank you!!!